# Running Reports SubReports and parameters from Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have to develop a asp.net web page which will execute some reports developed in SSRS . That report contains some other sub reports which are executed and results are saved into excel and pdf . 
My question is how to run this report and sub report  in Asp.net ?
I know how to execute single report but its not single report its report\ inside report 
can any one give me idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach a handler to the SubReportProcessing event of your report.  In vb.net:

```
AddHandler _report.SubreportProcessing, AddressOf RunSubReport
Sub RunSubReport(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SubreportProcessingEventArgs)
         'Set ds to your dataset        
         e.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("YourDataSourceName", ds))   
End Sub
```

See this stack overflow question for a discussion of adding parameters to the subreports: [Microsoft Reporting: Setting subreport parameters in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456982/microsoft-reporting-setting-subreport-parameters-in-code)

Adding them to the main report is straight forward:

```
'Passing in parameters to the report to display in the header
Dim paramCollection As New Collections.Generic.List(Of Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter)
paramCollection.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("startDate", startDate.ToShortDateString))
paramCollection.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("endDate", endDate.ToShortDateString))

'Set report parameters
_report.SetParameters(paramCollection)
```

Comment: Thanks Anna i need handler what about parameters because all reports shall be executed by certain parameters .